# Interpolate Temperature Data On Urban Area Using Cartopy

Tags: qgis, cartopy

I'm trying to interpolate temperature data observed on an urban area formed by 5 locations. I am using cartopy to interpolate and draw the map, however, when I run the script the temperature interpolation is not shown and I only get the layer of the urban area with the color palette. Can someone help me fix this error? The link of shapefile is

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u76k3yegvr09sx/LimiteAMG.shp?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxsmm3v2ey3ngsp/LimiteAMG.cpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx05n31dfkggbb6/LimiteAMG.dbf?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6nk0xczgjeen2d/LimiteAMG.prj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/royw7s51n2f0a6x/LimiteAMG.qpj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k44dcl1k5891qc/LimiteAMG.shx?dl=0

```
The Data is:

      Lat      Lon       tmax
  0   20.8208 -103.4434  22.8
  1   20.7019 -103.4728  17.7
  2   20.6833 -103.3500  24.9
  3   20.6280 -103.4261   NaN
  4   20.7205 -103.3172  26.4
  5   20.7355 -103.3782  25.7
  6   20.6593 -103.4136   NaN
  7   20.6740 -103.3842  25.8
  8   20.7585 -103.3904   NaN
  9   20.6230 -103.4265   NaN
 10   20.6209 -103.5004   NaN
 11   20.6758 -103.6439  24.5
 12   20.7084 -103.3901  24.0
 13   20.6353 -103.3994  23.0
 14   20.5994 -103.4133  25.0
 15   20.6302 -103.3422   NaN
 16   20.7400 -103.3122  23.0
 17   20.6061 -103.3475   NaN
 18   20.6400 -103.2900  23.0
 19   20.7248 -103.5305  24.0
 20   20.6238 -103.2401   NaN
 21   20.4753 -103.4451   NaN
```

the code is:

```py
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

from metpy.calc import get_wind_components
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.gridding.gridding_functions import interpolate,remove_nan_obervation 
from metpy.plots import add_metpy_logo
from metpy.units import units

to_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

data=pd.read_csv('/home/borisvladimir/Documentos/Datos/EMAs/EstacionesZMG/RedZMG.csv',usecols=(1,2,3),names=['Lat','Lon','tmax'],na_values=-99999,header=0)


fname='/home/borisvladimir/Dropbox/Diversos/Shapes/LimiteAMG.shp'
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())


lon = data['Lon'].values
lat = data['Lat'].values
xp, yp, _ = to_proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lon, lat).T


x_masked, y_masked, t = remove_nan_observations(xp, yp, data['tmax'].values)

tempx, tempy, temp = interpolate(x_masked, y_masked, t, interp_type='cressman', minimum_neighbors=3, search_radius=400000, hres=35000)
temp = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(temp), temp)

levels = list(range(-20, 20, 1))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
view = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=to_proj)

view.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black',  facecolor='white', alpha=0.5)


view.set_extent([-103.8, -103, 20.3, 21.099 ], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ZapLon,ZapLat=-103.50,20.80
GuadLon,GuadLat=-103.33,20.68
TonaLon,TonaLat=-103.21,20.62
TlaqLon,TlaqLat=-103.34,20.59
TlajoLon,TlajoLat=-103.44,20.47

plt.text(ZapLon,ZapLat,'Zapopan',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(GuadLon,GuadLat,'Guadalajara',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TonaLon,TonaLat,'Tonala',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TlaqLon,TlaqLat,'Tlaquepaque',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TlajoLon,TlajoLat,'Tlajomulco',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

mmb = view.pcolormesh(tempx, tempy,   temp,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(mmb, shrink=.4, pad=0.02, boundaries=levels)
plt.show()

how to solve this?
```

[image]

Comment: With only the .shp file, without .dbf ans .shx, we can do nothing

Comment: Sorry. The links loaded now

Comment: Your problem is not relating to the shapefiles since you are able to plot it. Do concentrate on the `pcolormesh` only.

Answer (score 1):

With the input data modified and saved as `lonlat_tmax.csv`.

```
Lat,Lon,tmax
  0,   20.8208, -103.4434,  22.8
  1,   20.7019, -103.4728,  17.7
  2,   20.6833, -103.3500,  24.9
  3,   20.6280, -103.4261,NaN
  4,   20.7205, -103.3172,  26.4
  5,   20.7355, -103.3782,  25.7
  6,   20.6593, -103.4136,NaN
  7,   20.6740, -103.3842,  25.8
  8,   20.7585, -103.3904,NaN
  9,   20.6230, -103.4265,NaN
 10,   20.6209, -103.5004,NaN
 11,   20.6758, -103.6439,  24.5
 12,   20.7084, -103.3901,  24.0
 13,   20.6353, -103.3994,  23.0
 14,   20.5994, -103.4133,  25.0
 15,   20.6302, -103.3422,NaN
 16,   20.7400, -103.3122,  23.0
 17,   20.6061, -103.3475,NaN
 18,   20.6400, -103.2900,  23.0
 19,   20.7248, -103.5305,  24.0
 20,   20.6238, -103.2401,NaN
 21,   20.4753, -103.4451,NaN
```

Here is the working code that plot the filled contour and towns locations.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm

# some settings
useproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# read data into pandas df
data = pd.read_csv('lonlat_tmax.csv', \
                   header=0, \
                   usecols=(1,2,3), \
                   names=['lat','lon','tmax'])

# flag data, select good/bad data for proper plotting
data['NaN_flag'] = data.tmax.isna()
good_data = data[ data.NaN_flag == False ]
bad_data = data[ data.NaN_flag == True ]

# extents of original data
xmin,xmax = data.lon.min(),data.lon.max()
ymin,ymax = data.lat.min(),data.lat.max()

# tmax limits
zmin, zmax = good_data.tmax.min(), good_data.tmax.max()

# create 2D meshgrid covering target area
numcols, numrows = 100, 100
xi = np.linspace(good_data.lon.min(), good_data.lon.max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(good_data.lat.min(), good_data.lat.max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# interpolate for zi of all grid points
# data points, values: x, y, Z
# interpolate points: (xi, yi)
# (output) interpolated values: zi

# use `good_data` dataframe for interpolation
zi = griddata(good_data.lon.values, \
              good_data.lat.values, \
              good_data.tmax, \
              xi, yi, interp='linear')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]  # for map extent
ax = fig.add_axes( rect, projection=useproj )

# prep colormap and color norm
levels = list(range(int(zmin)-1, int(zmax)+1, 1))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

# contours plot
conf = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, zorder=4, alpha=0.95, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
#ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.2, color='black') #nothing plotted in our case

# plot location names
ZapLon,ZapLat=-103.50,20.80
GuadLon,GuadLat=-103.33,20.68
TonaLon,TonaLat=-103.21,20.62
TlaqLon,TlaqLat=-103.34,20.59
TlajoLon,TlajoLat=-103.44,20.47

plt.text(ZapLon,ZapLat,'Zapopan', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), zorder=9, fontsize=12)
plt.text(GuadLon,GuadLat,'Guadalajara', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), zorder=9, fontsize=12)
plt.text(TonaLon,TonaLat,'Tonala', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), zorder=9, fontsize=12)
plt.text(TlaqLon,TlaqLat,'Tlaquepaque', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), zorder=9, fontsize=12)
plt.text(TlajoLon,TlajoLat,'Tlajomulco', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), zorder=9, fontsize=12)

#cbar = plt.colorbar(conf, orientation='horizontal', fraction=.04, pad=0.05)
cbar = plt.colorbar(conf, shrink=.5, pad=0.02, boundaries=levels)
cbar.set_label("Max Temp - celcius")

# set limits to cover all data points
pad = .07
ax.set_xlim(xmin-pad, xmax+pad)
ax.set_ylim(ymin-pad, ymax+pad)

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit and provide a quick "TL;DR" explanation of why this works compared to OP's approach? Otherwise anyone with the same problem will have to compare the code line by line!

Comment: @Simbamangu That will be `TL;DR`. I will wait for the OP's response first. Then only when I have spare time. Thanks for the comment anyway.